# Mockoon : How to get query parameters value with dot in parameter's name?

Tags: rest, mocking, mockoon

I try to mock `GET /wssorting/get-sortings?SearchCriteria.Names=abc123`

My response body is set to :

```
{
  param:  {{queryParam 'SearchCriteria.Names'}}
}
```

I tried with `queryParamRaw`, by escaping the dot `SearchCriteria\.Names`, using triple curly braces, but I get always the response body :

```
{
  param:
}
```

I cannot remove the dot in parameter name, it is a part of name.

Is it possible to use dot in query parameter names with Mockoon ?

Answer (score 0):

[Update 2024-01-01]

This is now possible since v4.1.0, which added support for dot notation and JSON Path to the `queryParam` and `queryParamRaw` helpers.

However, using the dot notation in the query parameters will not create an object as Mockoon is using `qs` to parse the parameters. Only the [bracket notation is supported](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/api-endpoints/routing/#query-parameters-arrays-and-objects).

It should work by calling the endpoint with:

`GET /wssorting/get-sortings?SearchCriteria[Names]=abc123`

---

This is not yet possible in Mockoon but will be, as part of the next release (in the coming days).
It's already possible using the `body` or `bodyRaw` helpers, which can be confusing.